# Calling async method from ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have a `ViewModel`, which makes use of [`Commanding`](https://blog.xamarin.com/simplifying-events-with-commanding/). In this `ViewModel` I want to access the [MediaPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin)
. With this plugin I have to call [`Initialize()`](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/issues/61#issuecomment-243572982). Because it uses `async` calls I have some timing problems.

This is my code:

```
public ICommand CameraCommand
{
    get { return _cameraCommand ?? (_cameraCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteCameraCommand(), () => CanExecuteCameraCommand())); }
}

public bool CanExecuteCameraCommand()
{
    // Check if initialized before calling properties
    if (!this.initialized)
        InitMedia();

    if (!this.initialized || !CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public async Task ExecuteCameraCommand()
{
    // Assure that it is initialized before calling method
    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions {});
    // ...
}

private void InitMedia()
{
    CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
    this.initialized = true;
}
```

With this code the app crashes with

> You must call Initialize() before calling any properties.
>   at Plugin.Media.MediaImplementation.get_IsCameraAvailable()

When I start the initialization in the constructor like with this code

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    InitData();
}

private async Task InitData()
{
    // ...
    await InitMedia();
}

private async Task InitMedia()
{
    await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
    this.initialized = true;
}

public bool CanExecuteCameraCommand()
{
    // Check if initialized before calling properties
    if (!this.initialized)
        return false;
    // ...
}
```

`CanExecuteCameraCommand()` is called before the initialization has finished. As a consequence `false` is returned and the button in the UI is disabled.

I'm testing this code in a Xamarin.Forms environment on a Windows 10 Mobile device (Windows 10 Universal).

Comment: Could you share the usage of MyViewModel?

Comment: It is used as [`BindingContext`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/) for my XAML.

Comment: Yes, are you calling BindingContex before Initialize? In xmal constructor is something like that?

public LoginPage()
        {
            vm = new LoginPageViewModel();

            BindingContext = vm;

            InitializeComponent();
        }

Comment: Yes, should I switch that?

Comment: Try something like that:

public LoginPage()
        {
            vm = new LoginPageViewModel();

            BindingContext = vm;

            InitializeComponent();

            vm.InitData();
        }

Make it public, and remove InitData form constructor ogf your viewmodel.

Comment: I'm calling `InitData()` without awaiting it as you proposed. `CanExecuteCameraCommand()` still returns `false`, because the initialization of the plugin hasn't finished yet.

Comment: You also can call OnAppearing xaml event:

protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            await vm.InitData();
        }

i think is better write an answer to better visualization

Comment: Because this isn't directly on a `Page` there is no `OnAppearing()` directly available. I would need to access the parent page somehow.

Comment: Now I tried to put the media plugin initialization code into `OnAppearing()` of the parent container page. The interesting part is, that `CanExecuteCameraCommand()` is called, before the create of the view with the view model has finished (I'm using `Activator.CreateInstance` for that). I would need to reevaluate the `CanExecuteCameraCommand()`. I tried to call it after setting the property, but the button is still disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and in particular you have not shown your implementation of the `Command` class. So I'm going to assume here that it's the `Command` class described in the Xamarin article you referenced.

The basic strategy for asynchronous initialization of your view model is this:

1. Disable any commands that depend on the result of the initialization, clear any properties (or set to appropriate default value) that depend on the result of the initialization.
2. Begin the asynchronous initialization.
3. Use some continuation mechanism (i.e. *don't block the thread*) to wait for the asynchronous initialization to complete.
4. When the initialization completes, re-enable previously disabled commands and update any relevant properties.

Based on the code you posted, it appears to me that the main thing missing is step #4. I.e. you're not doing anything to re-enable the previous disabled commands, even though you have a convenient place to do so:

```
private async Task InitMedia()
{
    await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
    this.initialized = true;
    _cameraCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
}
```

The `Command.ChangeCanExecute()` method raises the `CanExecuteChanged` event, so that controls bound to the command can be notified when the result of the `CanExecute()` method will be different. By calling this method when initialization is done, this should address the problem of the button remaining disabled even after initialization has completed.

One additional note: I would *not* call the `InitMedia()` method, or do any initialization at all, from the `CanExecuteCameraCommand()` method. Because initialization is asynchronous, it's not like you'll be able to successfully initialize before returning from that method anyway, and you've already got a call to the initialization from the constructor. The `ICommand.CanExecute()` implementation should be very simple, and strictly limited to checking the current state of things and returning the `bool` value required according to those results.

If the above does not address your question, please improve the question by providing a good MCVE, and explain in more precise details what is going wrong, what you've tried to fix it, and what specifically you are having trouble figuring out.

Comment: The `Command` implements the [`ICommand` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand(v=vs.110).aspx). I came with the same conclusion like you, that I have to recheck the status. It doesn't help to call `CanExecuteCameraCommand()` of the view model again, because the result isn't used anywhere. In the `ICommand` interface there is no `ChangeCanExecute()` method defined. So should I change the `Command` class if it's possible? Or can I trigger the `CanExecuteChanged` event somehow?

Comment: I think I have to implement `Command` as mentioned in the Xamarin article and not `ICommand` ...

Comment: _"The Command implements the ICommand interface"_ -- yes, but it _is_ the `Command` class, and that class (assuming you're using [the Xamarin one](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Command/)) _does_ have a `ChangeCanExecute()` method. You just need to make sure your `_cameraCommand` variable has the type `Command` and not `ICommand`. You don't have to _implement_ anything; the `Command` class you're using already does that...just make sure you don't restrict yourself by storing the instance reference in an `ICommand` variable.

Comment: Yes, I think that would be the solution to the problem. I'll try it out and give you the tick, when I'm finished.